# Testing for n lowercase characters in a string using a regex?

Tags: regex

Trying to create a regular expression that tests for n lowercase characters in a string.

So for a minimum of 2 characters for example, I thought something like `([a-z]){2,}` might work.

For the below test the first two are expected to pass:

```
const min = 2;
const tests = ['a2a#$2', 'a2a#$2a2', 'a2'];
const regex2: RegExp = new RegExp(`([a-z]){${min},}`);
tests.forEach((t) => {
  const valid = regex2.test(t);
  console.log(`t: ${t} is valid: ${valid}`);
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, I'm reposting this question as the previous one was deleted and IIUC this is against SO policy.  The question had an answer and SO values different points of view and different contexts with respect to questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844421/a-regular-expression-that-tests-for-n-lowercase-characters-in-a-string

Comment: IIUC it is also against SO policy to delete questions that already have answers.

Comment: You need to change 'n' in the title to 'at least two'. The selected answer does not generalize beyond 'n' equal to 2.

Comment: Well, I selected the answer because he's new to SO and there are a lot of good answers.  Please just let him know, and I'm sure hel'll update his answer.

Comment: I'm only concerned with the clarity of the question. The title and first line of the question suggest you want to test if the string contains exactly 'n' lowercase letters, but the following line and the code suggests you want to test if the string contains at least 'n' lowercase characters.

Comment: @CarySwoveland OK I added for example to the language.  You are right though.  The general idea is to test for n characters.

Comment: @Ole If you have issues with the reviews on your recent questions, you should perhaps raise the issue in a [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) post. I just came across this one in the Reopen Votes Review Queue: I'm not going to take side, so I'll "Skip" but I remember seeing another (related) post of yours that was closed under similar circumstances a few reviews ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might go the route of first stripping off all characters other than lowercase letters, then using a length assertion:

```js
var min = 2;
var tests = ['a2a#$2', 'a2a#$2a2', 'a2'];
tests.forEach(e => {
    if (e.replace(/[^a-z]+/g, "").length >= min) {
        console.log("MATCH:    " + e);
    }
    else {
        console.log("NO MATCH: " + e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[a-z].*[a-z]

Looks for lowercase, then anything or nothing in between, then lowercase again.

Try it out for yourself:

https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: If you can generalize your answer to n characters that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most scalable solution, but for 2 lowercase letters, you could do this: `.*[a-z].*[a-z].*`. Of course, this breaks down if you want to match 1000 lower case letters, you'd have to type [a-z] 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

To test if the string has exactly `n` lower-case letters, attempt to match the following regular expression:

```
^[^a-z]*(?:[a-z][^a-z]*){n}$
```

where `n` is replaced with the desired value.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcQLv9/1) for `n = 9`.

To match at least `n` lower-case letters use

```
[^a-z]*(?:[a-z][^a-z]*){n,}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the below, the match function will return the matches array. If there are no matches then it will return null. you can use matches.length to filter the array.

```
const min = 2;
const tests = ['a2a#$2', 'a2a#$2a2', 'a2'];
tests.forEach((t) => {
  const matches = t.match(/([a-z])/g)||[];
  console.log(`t: ${t} is valid: ${matches.length}`);
});
```